# How Do I correct the query Using Alias

Tags: sql-server

```
  Select Top 100

   A.Mnumber AS ContractNumber,
   B.Payor_Parent_Code,
   C.Payor_Parent_Name,
   B.Payor_Code,
   D.Payor_Name,
   E.Payor_Plan_Code,
   E.Payor_Plan_Name


from A

    left join B ON  A.[Payor_Plan_Code]=B.[Payor_Plan_Code]
    INNER JOIN  C ON B.[Payor_Parent_Code]=C.[Payor_Parent_Code]
    INNER JOIN D ON A.Payor_Code=D.Payor_Code
    INNER JOIN  E ON A.[Payor_Plan_Code]=E.[Payor_Plan_Code]

    WHERE NOT Payor_Parent_Name  = 'OTHER'
```

using this query i am getting an error Invalid object name 'A'. I would be thankful

Comment: what is A? Unless A is a table name (or view) it is undefined

Comment: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and any other letters you might choose are not good names for any types or objects in your schema (or for anything really). Create your tables and columns using descriptive names like `Players` for a table that contains player details or `PlayerPlans` etc.

Comment: It kind of looks like someone removed the table names from this query. Odd that there are extra spaces between JOIN and the aliases. I assume your tables are not called "A", "B" etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the same query worked when i used actual table names instead of Alias

Comment: To use an alias, you would do something like `FROM someTable A` then you can reference that table in joins: `JOIN someOtherTable B ON A.ID=B.A_ID` and where clauses: `WHERE A.someField = 'ABC'` and SQL will know that `A` points to `someTable` and `B` points to `someOtherTable`.  This makes your code much cleaner!  You can also use `AS` example: `FROM someTable AS A` -- the `AS` isn't necessary, but aids in readability.

Comment: Thanks . that was helpful

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `A.Mnumber AS ContractNumber`. Here you are referencing a column `Mnumber` from a an object `A` seemingly doesn't exist. This means you don't have a table or view named `A` but likely meant `SomeTable as A` based on the rest of your code.

[Aaron Bertrand: Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

For the tables you have, you should choose better aliases like `payorPlan`, `payorParent`, or something meaningful.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. There is `FROM A` in the query. But agree the names should be meaningfull.

Comment: totally missed that @JuanCarlosOropeza due to the spacing. Thanks for the note, updated